# creating dynamic drop down menu in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to create a dynamic database-driven drop down menu in a ColdFusion page.

I have written `ul` and `li` tags in a cfoutput tag, but nothing is displaying in the page.

```
<cfset dbsource="ndev9">
<cfset dbschema="security">
<cfset dbuserid="security">
<cfset dbpw="sec">
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menubar_new.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bannerstyle.css">
<cfquery name="main_menu" datasource="#dbsource#" username="#dbuserid#" password="#dbpw#">
    select * from #dbschema#.main_menu order by MAIN_MENU_ORDER
</cfquery>

<body>
<cfoutput>  
<ul id="menu_new">

 <cfloop query="main_menu">


    <li><a href="#main_menu.main_menu_URL_0#" class="HeaderLink">#main_menu.main_menu_name#</a></li>
</cfloop>   
</ul>
</cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How many records does your query return?

Comment: Does the query named `main_menu` actually return results? Try adding <cfdump var="#main_menu#" /> to the page.

Comment: Also, you don't need both `<cfoutput>` and `<cfloop>` tag s. Remove the outer `<cfoutput>`, then change `<cfloop query="main_menu">` to `<cfoutput query="main_menu">`.